# How can I customize embedded Twitter Feed CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter

I need a kind help from you guys. Currently, I am building a website from scratch, the client wants to add his twitter feed to the footer of the website.

But the problem is I could not customize the default twitter feed style. Here is the screenshot please have a look https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgS5I.png

Please help me to customize the twitter feed by CSS.

Kind Regards 
Asad

Comment: You should really take a https://stackoverflow.com/tour and read more about https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking . You have multiple questions with same issues: no MCVE, no showing of your own efforts etc. Please help others help you. Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I'm a relative novice, but I had some success using the following javascript function and calling it in the `<body>` element.  Because Twitter grabs its styling through a script, it renders last so any styles in your css sheet will be overruled.  The fix is to use a script to directly overwrite the embedded twitter stylesheets.

Try this:

1. Insert the following script into your website's header:

   ```
   <script>
     var widgetCSS = "" +
       "#twitter-widget-0{width: 100% !important;}"+
       ".timeline-Tweet-text{color:red; font-size:20px !important;}" +
       ".timeline-Widget{background-color: red;" +
       ".TweetAuthor-name{color:white !important;}";

     function customTwitter(){
       var w = document.getElementById("twitter-widget-0").contentDocument;

       var s = document.createElement("style");
       s.innerHTML = widgetCSS;
       s.type = "text/css";
       w.head.appendChild(s);
     }
   </script>
   ```
2. Change the value of var widgetCSS to whatever you want your CSS to look like. I used the inspect feature on chrome to identify the classes that needed to be changed.
3. Finally, call the function paint(); in the body of html like so:

   ```
   <body onload="customTwitter();">
   ```

...and you should see the changes to the affected elements.

Hope this helps.